# Combination of WPF TextBox and RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, richtextbox

I am writing a small editor, based on a WPF (c#) TextBox. For some functionality the method getRectFromCharacterIndex(), which is only implemented in the TextBox-class is necessary. Furthermore I've got to do some syntax-highlighting in my program. Normally this is easy to handle in a TextBlock or a RichTextBox. Unfortunately these two Controls don't include Methods like the one mentioned above. Has anyone an idea, how to format and/or color single Characters in a normal TextBox with a small workaround?

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

I did the same effort in the past and I decided to move to this: http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx almost all the work you need is done here.

Comment: Hello Felice,
thank you very much for your help. I had a quick look at the link you posted. The problem is, that it's a bit oversized for my purposes. My Editor-Control is just a small part of a bigger project. I also have to mention, that it's a readonly control which doesn't have to handle any user-input directly.